# Issues related to column chart

Tags: php, javascript

Actually, i want to draw a graph between number of users and date(in which user added) and the data i will push into graph is dynamic. So, please tell me any solution for draw this graph.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Are you stuck anywhere ? Post your code snippet.

Comment: I've provided you a bunch of links, that should get you started :)  Now its just a matter of choosing a library that suits you best....the Javascript ones are usually 'fancier' than the pure PHP classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to use is Google Charts, see:
https://developers.google.com/chart/

Answer (score 0):

There are many packages out there to do what you want...
Some in javascript, some in PHP.
Most of the time, you do this with Ajax and JSON data.

Heres a list....this will help you get started.

Highcharts (JS)

http://www.highcharts.com/

Flot Charts (JS)

http://www.flotcharts.org/

Fusion Charts (JS)

http://www.fusioncharts.com/

pCharts (PHP)

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

SVGGraph (PHP)

http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php

JpGraph (PHP)

http://jpgraph.net/